# Knockout Intellisense Priority in VS2013

Tags: knockout.js, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I am having an issue when using intellisense for javascript, that while trying to type 'ko.' to call the knockout library, my VS2013 intellisense suggests and automatically implements 'KeyOperation' each time the above 3 letters are typed, and its driving me crazy!
I have set the priority in 
 Tools->Options->Javascript->Intellisense->References
and put the ~/Scripts/_references.js at the top of the list, but i have the same issue.

'ko' does appear in the intellisense list but its way down the tree. 
Has anyone had this issue and/or has found a fix?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fresh solution / project? Perhaps it's specific to your current solution? Also, have you tried disabling all extensions / addons?

Comment: Hi @Jeroen, I am getting the issue with all projects. So I just realised that Resharper was overriding the intellisense settings that I set in Visual Studio! So I have set "Resharper - Intellisense -> Javascript to off, and I ko intellisense is back! Thanks heaps - i forgot about resharper overriding it..

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resharper was overriding the intellisense of visual studio, so by setting intellisense off for javascript under: Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> Intellisense I now get much tighter javascript intellisense, limited to the properties of the current object, and the KeyOperation is now nowhere to be found when typing ko!
Hope this helps someone!